# Excel VBA - My code runs fine by itself, but within a bigger code, does not

Tags: excel, vba, do-loops

I have a do loop that uses an array to find Keywords within a cell and replaces them with their corresponding MachineNames array value. When I run this by itself, it works perfectly. When I run it within a bigger code, it does appear to loop through each of the array items (I used breakpoints to watch this), but for some reason it no longer "sees" the value in the cell. It simply loops through all the Keywords, decides none of them were found (even if one is in the cell)... any thoughts or help is appreciated!

```
'MACHINENAME (if it is written in the description.)
Dim Keywords As Variant
Dim MachineNames As Variant

Keywords = Array("Robot", "Robot 1", "Robot 2", "Robot 3", "Robot 4", "Robot 5", "Robot 6", "FA ", "FA 1", "FA1", "FA 2", "FA2", "FA 3", "FA3", "FA 4", "FA4", "FA 5", "FA5", "FA 6", "FA6", "FA 7", "FA7", "FA 8", "FA8", "FA 9", "FA9", "FA 10", "FA10", "FA 11", "FA11", "FA 12", "FA12", "Sta120", "Sta95", "Sta90C", "Sta 120", "Sta 95", "Sta 90C", "St120", "St95", "St90C", "St 120", "St 95", "St 90C", "Flex Arc", "Flex Arch", _
    "Hammond", "Acme", "Polish", "SAM", "Tank", "Fender", "Welder", "Balance", "PICO", "Gravity", "Vin Mark", "Vin Stamp", "Telesis", "Pinstamp", "Pin stamp", "Buff", "Wet", "E-Coat", "E Coat", "Ecoat", "Carrier", "Line", "Line 1", "Line1", "Line 2", "Line2", "Line 3", "Line3", "Line 4", "Line4", "Line 5", "Line5", "Line 6", "Line6", _
    "Sta100", "Sta30", "Sta150", "Sta 100", "Sta 30", "Sta 150", "St100", "St30", "St150", "St 100", "St 30", "St 150", "Laser", "Laser 1", "Laser1", "Laser 2", "Laser2", "Laser 3", "Laser3", "Laser 4", "Laser4", "Laser 5", "Laser5", "Laser 6", "Laser6", "Laser Seamer", "Laser Seam", "Laser Seemer", "Vin Laser", "Monode", "Sub", _
    "Tip", "Tip Change", "Press ", "Swingarm Press", "Swing arm Press", "Bearing Press", "Medallion Press", "Footboard Press", "AIDA", "AIDA Press", "Cushion", "Press 1", "Press1", "Press 2", "Press2", "Press 3", "Press3", "Press 4", "Press4")

MachineNames = Array("Robot", "Robot 1", "Robot 2", "Robot 3", "Robot 4", "Robot 5", "Robot 6", "FA", "FA 1", "FA 1", "FA 2", "FA 2", "FA 3", "FA 3", "FA 4", "FA 4", "FA 5", "FA 5", "FA 6", "FA 6", "FA 7", "FA 7", "FA 8", "FA 8", "FA 9", "FA 9", "FA 10", "FA 10", "FA 11", "FA 11", "FA 12", "FA 12", "FA 4", "FA 3", "FA 10", "FA 4", "FA 3", "FA 10", "FA 4", "FA 3", "FA 10", "FA 4", "FA 3", "FA 10", "FA", "FA", _
    "Polish (Hammond)", "Polish (Acme)", "Polish", "SAM", "Tank", "Fender", "Welder", "Balance", "PICO", "Gravity", "Vin Stamp", "Vin Stamp", "Pinstamp", "Pinstamp", "Pinstamp", "Buff", "Wet", "E-Coat", "E-Coat", "E-Coat", "Carrier", "Line", "Line 1", "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 3", "Line 4", "Line 4", "Line 5", "Line 5", "Line 6", "Line 6", _
    "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser", "Laser 1", "Laser 1", "Laser 2", "Laser 2", "Laser 3", "Laser 3", "Laser 4", "Laser 4", "Laser 5", "Laser 5", "Laser 6", "Laser 6", _
    "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Seamer)", "Laser (Vin)", "Laser (Monode)", "Sub", "Tip", "Tip", "Press", "Press (Swingarm)", "Press (Swingarm)", "Press (Bearing)", "Press (Medallion)", "Press (Footboard)", "Press (AIDA)", "Press (AIDA)", "Press", "Press 1", "Press 1", "Press 2", "Press 2", "Press 3", "Press 3", "Press 4", "Press 4")

Range("A2").activate 'the cell to look in for the keyword

Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) <> "" 'the cell we are placing the found MachineName Value in (or blank if none are found.) We will eventually hit previous data, so it will stop if this cell is not blank.
    For i = 0 To UBound(Keywords)
                    Set C = ActiveCell.Find(Keywords(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not C Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = MachineNames(i) 
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).activate
Loop
```

Comment: you need to  specify the Parent sheet of the range `worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")`

Comment: Hi Scott Craner- Thanks for your response. I actually call this module- so in the main it looks like `sub test() worksheets("All Data").activate call module.findkeywords call module.othermodule call module.othermodule2 (etc) end sub` does that work okay, or should I re-specify?

Comment: One should always avoid `.Activate` and `.Select` and just specify the parents directly.  Your loop should be a for loop and not a Do loop.  Find the last row and loop through that.  It is even better practice to use arrays.

Comment: Could you explain how I would specify the parents in the call statement without using activate or select? I didn't know there was another way. And as far as the for loop- how do I specify the last blank cell when this is a range that could change? (Ex. B1 to B4 or other times B1 to B70) I realize Stack Overflow is not to have people just write the whole code for me, but a little more specification would definitely help me get started. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Update: I see now that you can "Set" a worksheet or range. I can do that. I am still a little confused on how a for loop would work for this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that the code doesn't seems to "see" the value in the cell which in your code is introduced by

```
Range("A2").activate
```

I would try to replace this with the full reference of the cell which would be something like:

```
Application.Workbooks("book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Activate
```

Replace book1 with your file name and Sheet1 with your worksheet.
My assumption is that Range("A2").Activate activates A2 on some other sheet but cannot be sure unless see the whole code.
Hope that helps ;)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much Angel. I wonder why the selection of the workbook and sheet before calling this module didnt translate into it though. Maybe what Scott Craner said about trying to Set it would work.

Comment: Welcome, glat to hear it helped! Thanks for your feedback :)